# Any alternates for browser bookmarks or any way to properly arrane in browser itself?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, bookmarks

I bookmark a lot of technical articles for future reference but with time the list is getting bigger and bigger. I've a bookmark folder in my browser and then all articles bookmarked inside it. Since the list is getting bigger I may have trouble soon finding the right blog post quickly at the time of need.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Welcome John! Funny you ask this just now. I've been trying to figure out the best way to ask this question myself. I wasn't sure exactly where to do so, and considered here and https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I use Vivaldi, which is a chromium based browser, and in the bookmark tab, I can simply search for bookmarks, which makes it easy to find any bookmark along a huge collection of bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome allows you to create a new folder when you save a bookmark.  It doesn't allow creating a new bookmark folder in the bookmark manager, for some reason.  Firefox bookmark manager allows creating subfolders by right-clicking.

Assuming that the articles are on different topics, you might create a folder for each topic and store articles under the correct topic.  That would make searching easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Rewind (I'm the author)

It was created exactly with this problem in mind (huge collection of bookmarks), it displays them by date, so you only have a small subset of bookmarks to check at a time. If you want to find a specific bookmark, you have a super-fast search engine.

https://rewind.netlify.app/